# How I do a subtraction 2 numbers in a sequential circuit?

Tags: verilog, sequential, circuit, subtraction

I need to do a circuit in which I subtract 2 numbers. I believe I need to use the SUM and a sign bit, and some masks, but I cannot figure out how to put it together.

[LATER EDIT]

i tried to do "15-3".

15 in binary is 1111
3 in binary is  0011

I have added a bit for the sign 0 for + and 1 for -

So now i have: 0 1111 + 1 0011 = 100010 and to this I make a XOR with the sign mask 1 0000. This is where I get stuck.

[Even later edit]

I think I found another way to look at the problem. 
I'll be using 2 shift registers to load the 2 numbers. The output of each shift register will be the input of a NOR gate performing a NOR with 0. (This is to transform 0101 into 1010) Then the 2 outputs of these gates will be connected to the input of the SUM.
My question is how can I transform back from 1 bit to a 8 bit data before entering the SUM ?

Comment: you should add more details to what you have tried

Comment: You tagged this verilog, so what's wrong with `assign result = 15 - 3`? Or are you trying to build this by hand at the gate level?

Comment: I have this assignment, and I have to do all these steps: draw sequential circuit, draw logic diagram and then the verilog simulation.

Answer (score 2):

If you learn about [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) as a way of inverting (negating) a number, the problem will become much simpler.

There are a few ways to represent negative numbers.

1) Sign Magnitude (Add sign bit)

```
0 0011 =>  3
1 0011 => -3
```

2) Ones Complement (bitwise invert)

```
0011 =>  3
1100 => -3
```

3) Two's Complement (one's complement + 1)

```
0011             =>  3
1100 + 1 => 1101 => -3
```

Two's Complement adds an efficiency as it removes duplicate 0 codes (0000=>0 and 1111=>-0) that One's complement has.

Two's Complement also has the property that the numbers can be added together as normal.
For `15 - 3` actually perform `15 + (-3)`.

To find out how to add binary number take a quick look at [ripple adders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29).

First create a Half adder, adding 2 bits generating a sum and a carry. Use your half adders + XOR gate to build a full adder, A+B+Carry in, generating SUM  and Carry Out (all 1 bit). You can then chain these together making an X width full adder.

Comment:  for a concise explanation of why 1's complement is inferior to 2's complement.

Answer (score 0):

The half adder is an example of a simple, functional digital circuit built from two logic gates. The half adder adds to one-bit binary numbers (AB). The output is the sum of the two bits (S) and the carry (C). Note how the same two inputs are directed to two different gates.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GAe6.png)